# How to configure Swagger with Fastify to serve different versions of API documentation in different routes

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, fastify, fastify-swagger

I'm working on a Node.js project using Fastify with TypeScript, and I'm trying to generate API documentation using Swagger for multiple versions of my API ('v1' and 'v2'). I have opted to use the `@fastify/swagger` along with `@fastify/swagger-ui` plugins.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';
import fastifySwagger from '@fastify/swagger';
import fastifySwaggerUi from '@fastify/swagger-ui';

const supportedVersions = ['v1', 'v2'];

/**
 * @description These plugins add self-generated documentation based on route schemas
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/swagger
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/swagger-ui
 */
export default fp(async (fastify: FastifyInstance) => {
    supportedVersions.forEach(async (version) => {
        await fastify.register(async function (fastify) {
            await fastify.register(fastifySwagger);

            await fastify.register(fastifySwaggerUi, {
                routePrefix: `/${version}/documentation`,
                uiConfig: {
                    docExpansion: 'full',
                    deepLinking: false,
                },
                transformSpecification: (swaggerObject, request, reply) => {
                    let tempSwaggerObject: Record<string, any> = swaggerObject;
                    let version = request.url.split('/').find((item) => item.startsWith('v'));

                    tempSwaggerObject.info = {
                        title: 'Test',
                        description: `Test API documentation for version ${version}`,
                        version: `${version}`,
                    };

                    let tempPaths = tempSwaggerObject.paths;

                    Object.keys(tempPaths).forEach((path) => {
                        if (path !== `/${version}/`) {
                            delete tempPaths[path];
                        }
                    });

                    tempSwaggerObject.paths = { ...tempPaths };
                    return tempSwaggerObject;
                },
                transformSpecificationClone: true,
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This setup successfully creates the following URLs for the different versions of the API documentation:

```
   http://127.0.0.1:4000/v1/documentation/static/index.html
   http://127.0.0.1:4000/v2/documentation/static/index.html
```

However, the Swagger UI is not picking up the schemas from the routes, there is at least a GET method in each route for testing, but the generated documentation is empty:

[image]

The project's folder structure is as follows:

[image]

I'm using @fastify/swagger@8.4.0, @fastify/swagger-ui@1.8.1, @fastify/autoload@5.7.1, fastify@4.17.0, and fastify-plugin@4.5.0.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I would greatly appreciate any insights on properly configuring Swagger with Fastify to serve multiple versions of API documentation.

Comment: I'm currently looking for the same solution, although I'd not go as far as separating the whole swagger docs by v1 or v2, I'm fine with having the endpoints grouped by the versioning and then grouped by the endpoint.